# Get data in Azure ML directly from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-pipelines

I currently have a pipeline in Azure machine learning that's taking in data from the datastore and then training a model on it. In order to get the data into the datastore to begin with I have to manually add it from the SQL Server by using their UI.

My question is, is there a way to automate the process of retrieving the data from a SQL Server into an Azure ML pipeline, or at least into the datastore?

Comment: Have you read this article ? : https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/16/automated-machine-learning-from-sql-server-with-azure-machine-learning/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Azure ML studio and click a datastore and provide required details .

[image: Ref1]

Go to Data and register the data assert .Please follow below Steps:

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

**Step 4:**

[image]

> **Visualize the data in workflow**

[image]